# GETTING AttributeError: function 'Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion' not found ERROR WHILE ACCESSING FUNCTION FROM DLL

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, microchip

I am trying to access some functions from the DLL file by using python for MCP2221 evaluation board my code is :

```
from ctypes import*
mydll=cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\535283\\Desktop\\dll\\dll\\mcp2221_dll_um_x86.dll") 
mydll.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(wchar_t *version)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\535283\Desktop\dll\dll>python dll.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dll.py", line 3, in <module>     mydll.Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(wchar_t *version)  
 File "C:\Users\535283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 360, in __getattr__     func = self.__getitem__(name)  
 File "C:\Users\535283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __getitem__     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
 AttributeError: function 'Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion' not found
```

Comment: You can format the error a bit better by prefixing it by 4 spaces, that will make it easier to read.

Comment: What is the C header file declaration of the function?

Comment: the function declaration is like this  --                                                        int Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(wchar_t* version)
==================================================================================================
Description: Returns the version number of the DLL
Parameters:
Inputs: None
Outputs:
(wchar_t*) version - variable that will store the library version. The library version is a 10 character wchar string.
Returns: 0 for success or error code.      @MarkTolonen